# Loop through two lists, grab values from first, add them to the second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/vr45Ln29/

I would like to loop through the `img`s in the first `ul`, grab the `src` for each then loop through the second `ul` `img`s and stick the `src` urls from the first list into the second.

To clarify, I just want the urls to be pulled from the `img`s above and pasted into the `src` attr for each `img` below.

I simply can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i modified your fiddle, here is a version that works

```js
var container = $('.slider-container'),
   bigImgs = container.find('li img');

   
   bigImgs.each(function() {
                $("ul","div.slider-thumbnails").append("<li><img width='150' src='" +$(this).attr("src") + "'/></li>");
    
   });
```

```html
<div class="main-slider">
 <ul class="slider-container">
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="one">
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x250" alt="two">
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200" alt="three">
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x100" alt="four">
   </a>
  </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<!-- Thumbnails -->
<div class="slider-thumbnails">
 <ul>
  
 </ul>
</div>
```

basically, you can just create the thumbnails dynamically at load.